# Upgrading Win7 to Win8 on a dual boot with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: upgrade

Please can someone comment if my current setup of Windows 7 with dual boot of Ubuntu 12.04 will continue to boot and work OK after upgrade my win 7 to win8 OR are there things I need to do first?

thanks

Comment: You need to explain that a little bit more. What partition layout? UEFI or BIOS? Dual-booting only with Ubuntu's bootloader (GRUB), selecting different hard drives at boot or something else? By default you probably need to reinstall Ubuntu's bootloader with the Live DVD as Windows Setup usually overwrites it on BIOS based systems.

Answer (score 2):

Installing Windows will cause for the Windows bootloader to take the place of GRUB (the Linux bootloader).  After the install, only Windows will boot.

To fix this, you need any live CD/DVD with Ubuntu/Fedora/Debian/etc.

After upgrade you need to boot with this live CD/DVD and repair the GRUB2 bootloader.

For repair you should do this:

1. For example, you boot with Ubuntu life CD
2. Press [Alt]+[F2] and type `gnome-terminal`
3. Then you need to know your disk partitioning. execute this command (in the terminal) for it:

   ```
   sudo fdisk -l
   ```

You should see sth like that:

```
/dev/sda1 29 8369 66999082+ 83 Linux
/dev/sda2 * 8370 13995 45190845 7 HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda3 13996 14593 4803435 5 Extended
```

You can see, that Linux partition (in this option)is /dev/sda1

1. Let's mount it in the /mnt directory with this command:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
   ```
2. After that you have to write grub into the MBR, type this:

   ```
   sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
   ```
3. You should see the grub menu at the next boot. If you don't, do the speps 1-4 again and after that execute this command:

   ```
   sudo update-grub --output=/mnt/boot/grub/grub.cfg
   ```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You need to be very careful as Windows 8 will probably clobber you MBR (boot area). Basically this means you will only be able to boot into Windows 8 even though Ubuntu will still be there on another partition (just invisible to the boot loader). There a numerous guides showing how to backup and restore your boot area post windows installation. I'm sure they will work for windows 8 but maybe someone with more specific knowledge of windows 8 installation can chime in just to make sure I don't point you to some out of date or incorrect information. 
**Obviously - Make sure you backup you system beforehand anyway...**